# Troubleshooting Dreamhost + Passenger + Django

Tags: python, django, nginx, passenger, dreamhost

I have a website that was happily running on Dreamhost + Passenger + Django for several years. Recently (last Thursday) it looks like Dreamhost updated Passenger under the hood without notifying me, and this has caused the website to go down.

Here is the installed (hosted) Passenger directory:

```
$ pwd
/dh/nginx/passenger
$ ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 2014-05-15 13:40 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root   76 2012-06-27 17:54 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1056 2013-10-26 15:00 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 2014-05-15 13:40 bin
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root   92 2014-05-15 13:40 buildout
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 2014-05-15 13:40 dev
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 2014-05-15 13:40 doc
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root  139 2014-05-15 13:40 ext
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 2014-05-15 13:40 helper-scripts
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   69 2014-05-15 13:40 lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  137 2014-05-15 13:40 man
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   38 2014-05-15 13:40 node_lib
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1243 2013-10-26 15:00 passenger.gemspec
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 2014-05-15 13:40 resources
```

These file updates approximate to the time the site went down.

I thought it might be a simple case of restarting Passenger by `touch`-ing `/path/to/app/tmp/restart.txt` however that does not seem to have worked. Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:** The web server is Nginx. I assume that I can just reload Nginx and that will refresh all connections through Passenger?

`sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload`

**Edit 2:** The file in question that throws the error is:

`/dh/nginx/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py`

with the error:

```
File "/dh/nginx/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 171
    buf = b''
            ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Interestingly, although it looks like Passenger was updated on 2014-05-15, all these helper scripts date back to 2013-10-26. Is it something simple like these helper scripts are out of date with the newly installed version of Passenger? I had thought that Passenger itself was language agnostic?

**Edit 3:** The `virtualenv` being ignored

So, the system installed version of Python is 2.5.2, but my `virtualenv` Python I have built the application in is 2.6.8. So this error shouldn't even be showing up. I have added my 2.6.8 Python interpreter as per the [instructions](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Passenger#Passenger_WSGI_and_virtualenv) but it is still not working and the error message still suggests that the old Python interpreter is being used. Any ideas?

**Edit 4:** The correct (and valid) virtualenv Python interpreter is being used (2.6.8)

```
import sys, os
INTERP = "/home/<user>/venv/tcs/bin/python2.6"
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
# print(sys.version)
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '/home/<user>/<application>/<dir>'))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "project.settings"
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

(<user>, <application> and <dir> hidden for obvious reasons)
```

When I uncomment the `print(sys.version)` I get the following output:

```
2.6.8 (unknown, Jul 10 2012, 08:03:16)
[GCC 4.3.2]
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I'm running into a very similar problem. What's your error message, by the way?

Comment: I posted the error msg I was getting in **Edit 2**

Comment: Added more info about my virtualenv Python (2.6.8) in **Edit 3** which should be the one being used

Comment: I heard back from Dreamhost: " With the new version of Passenger redirecting STDOUT causes errors because Passenger uses that output to track the processes." They commented the line `#sys.stdout=sys.stderr` in my WSGI handler script, and that fixed the error. Not sure if this fits your case, but hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are running Python 2.5 or earlier, which did not support the byte string declaration syntax. Phusion Passenger [requires Python 2.6 or later](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_supported_operating_systems_and_languages).

Comment: Thanks! I got an email from the Dreamhost folks stating that exact thing.

Comment: Hmm. The Python version I am running in my `virtualenv` for the website is 2.6.8. I have followed the [instructions](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Passenger#Passenger_WSGI_and_virtualenv) for adding a virtual host Python interpreter, but it is still failing. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this same question on the Phusion Passenger list and Hongli also answered me there (thanks Hongli!!):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/cYBgUPX_ICA

Dreamhost's documentation is out-of-date, and their support team is not well versed in Phusion Passenger configs/issues.

It turns out that Passenger also requires at least Python 2.6 to **even start up** (if you are using it for Python apps or frameworks like Django), *prior* to loading your defined `virtualenv` Python interpreter in your `passenger_wsgi.py` file. To make this happen you need to modify how Nginx is configured...

Edit your Nginx config file (`nginx.conf`) and add the following line:

```
http {
    passenger_root ...;

    # Use Python 2.6 by default.
    passenger_python /home/<user>/venv/<venv-name>/bin/python2.6;


    server {
        <snip>
    }
}
```

This forces Passenger to use *the defined* Python interpreter in `passenger_python` for starting up. Voila! - a running webserver once again.

[Relevant anchor in the Phusion Passenger Nginx webpage](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_passenger_python_lt_filename_gt)